# What widespread languages are LL(k)?

Tags: parsing

Alrighty, by LL(k) languages, I mean programming languages whose parsers can be described by grammars which are LL(k).

these are my guesses:

pascal 
lisp 
xml and friends

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the definition of "language". If you ask

> What programming language is correctly
>   parsable with an LL(k) parser?

then none is, not even pascal or xml, since they are all context-sensitive. A context-free grammar cannot detect errors such as identifiers that are used without being defined, or match the opening and closing tag in XML. If you ask

> What programming language can be
>   conveniently parsed with an LL(k)
>   parser, assuming that further analysis
>   of well-formedness must be added on
>   top of parsing?

then [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is proof that [nearly every programming language](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) can be processed with a (version of an) LL(k) parser.

Comment: Also, CFG can't describe "types", and allowed operations depending on types.

Comment: @Arak: right; this is probably more relevant than the need for declarations. Interestingly enough, Algol-68 solved both problems with a two-level grammar.

Comment: @Martin This makes assumptions about what a programming language syntax allows or restricts and toss together the lexical parsing and semantic analysis phases. I think a restructure of the answer would be helpful.

Comment: @Ellery: maybe you should ask the question more clearly if you want a different answer.

Comment: @Ellery: Then you should edit your question to reflect what you have just said, your question just asks for languages that can be parsed via LL(k).

Comment: @Ellery: No matter what type of parser you're creating, efficiency heavily depends on how you express the grammar. I think #2 is better stated as "ANTLR can parse all sorts of crap if you're willing to use it effectively."